# Prevent Windows from installing a device automatically

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, drivers, hdmi

I have an optical cable attached to my motherboard that I want to use as the audio output. However, Windows 10 keeps installing "High Definition Audio device" which outputs the audio through my GPU and the HDMI port. Changing the default output device does not help because optical output won't work if the HDMI-option exists even if it's not selected.

My workaround is to open Device manager and uninstall the device (High Definition Audio device) everytime I reboot or wake up my computer, for that is the only way to make it work.

[image: Screenshot of what devices are installed.]

Do you have any suggestions for where I should look to prevent this from happening? Write a script that uninstalls the device? Remove some driver files? Do some regedit magic?

EDIT: It **could** be a problem with my AVR. Not sure how, but if it tries to use the HDMI as the audio source while my PC actually outputs to the S/PDIF. Though, it still doesn't do that when the device is uninstalled without touching any cables and the HDMI is still attached and used for video...

Comment: It's the first time I hear such a thing. As a general rule all devices should be installed (drivers, etc.) and available. Users can then select any card from the list anytime. What happens when you explicitly select the onboard one (Realtek)?

Comment: @MichaelBay I can select the Realtek output and the green bar even pulses showing that sound should be playing. But everything remains silent until I uninstall the other one.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
dism /online /get-drivers /all /format:table

-------------------------------------- | ---------------------------------------- | ----- | ----------------------- | ----------------------------------------- | ---------- | -----------------
Published Name                         | Original File Name                       | Inbox | Class Name              | Provider Name                             | Date       | Version
-------------------------------------- | ---------------------------------------- | ----- | ----------------------- | ----------------------------------------- | ---------- | -----------------
1394.inf                               | 1394.inf                                 | Yes   | 1394                    | Microsoft                                 | 6/21/2006  | 10.0.19041.1
3ware.inf                              | 3ware.inf                                | Yes   | SCSIAdapter             | LSI                                       | 4/11/2013  | 5.1.0.51
61883.inf                              | 61883.inf                                | Yes   | 61883                   | Microsoft                                 | 6/21/2006  | 10.0.19041.1
acpi.inf                               | acpi.inf                                 | Yes   | System                  | Microsoft                                 | 6/21/2006  | 10.0.19041.3271
acpidev.inf                            | acpidev.inf                              | Yes   | System                  | Microsoft                                 | 6/21/2006  | 10.0.19041.1
acpipagr.inf                           | acpipagr.inf                             | Yes   | System                  | Microsoft                                 | 6/21/2006  | 10.0.19041.1
acpipmi.inf                            | acpipmi.inf                              | Yes   | System                  | Microsoft                                 | 6/21/2006  | 10.0.19041.1
```

However, further down the list you will  notice how the first column becomes all oem####.inf files.

```
-------------------------------------- | ---------------------------------------- | ----- | ----------------------- | ----------------------------------------- | ---------- | -----------------
Published Name                         | Original File Name                       | Inbox | Class Name              | Provider Name                             | Date       | Version
-------------------------------------- | ---------------------------------------- | ----- | ----------------------- | ----------------------------------------- | ---------- | -----------------
oem1.inf                               | hpanalyticsext.inf                       | No    | Extension               | HP Inc.                                   | 11/14/2018 | 1.6.856.0
oem10.inf                              | mesrl.inf                                | No    | Ports                   | Intel                                     | 12/11/2022 | 2251.4.1.0
oem100.inf                             | jasperlake+systemnorthpeak.inf           | No    | System                  | INTEL                                     | 7/18/1968  | 10.1.29.4
oem101.inf                             | minictadriver.inf                        | No    | CTA Driver Devices      | Intel Corporation                         | 2/18/2021  | 27.20.100.9316
oem102.inf                             | memcntrl.inf                             | No    | System                  | Intel                                     | 2/18/2021  | 27.20.100.9316
oem103.inf                             | jasperlakepch-nsystem.inf                | No    | System                  | INTEL                                     | 7/18/1968  | 10.1.32.3
oem105.inf                             | iaahcic.inf                              | No    | HDC                     | Intel Corporation                         | 7/8/2019   | 17.5.2.1024
oem11.inf                              | hpdsuextension.inf                       | No    | Extension               | HP Development Company, L.P.              | 6/17/2022  | 8.10.6.45385
```

You now need to find your driver name in column #2.  Then get the name from column #1.

From an Administrative Command prompt

```
pnputil /delete-driver oem0.inf /force
```

Replace the oem0.inf with the information from column 1.

Comment: It's called hdaudio.inf, not oem_anything.inf. Also the latter command says `Failed to delete dirver package: The specified file is not an installed OEM INF` . Next, I will try to play around with the NVIDIA GPU drivers.

Comment: Windows internal renames most drivers as oem*.inf that is why I provided instructions on how to lookup the correct name.

Comment: For me, both Published Name and Original File Name were `audioendpoint.inf` and I had the same error as @Antti_M.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish wnat you want is to open old sound settings:

[image: Sound Settings]

And just disable the output(s) you don't need so that Windows and the apps won't use those.

Note that if you are performing clean video driver install every time you update your video drivers either by selecting an option in the driver setup or by using 3rd party tools such as DDU or CCleaner (which I don't recommend), you might have to re-disable the output(s) afterwards because they usually get re-enabled after clean install.

Also, you may want to check if your desired output is set as default in Windows, and if it is, then also check if it is also chosen in the application / player you use. There is a possibility that the app is using the wrong output. Sometimes this can happen if the AVR indicates that it doesn't support specific PCM encoding over SPDIF and then the app falls back to HDMI (in most media players those settings are usually under audio decoder settings).

Finally, most AVRs have an option to choose the matching audio source for each video input so be sure to check your AVR input settings. Note that if it has more than one HDMI maybe they are not all equal in terms of whether choosing different audio source is supported.

Answer (score -1):

You can go into Device Manager, Select the device and inside its Settings>Driver There is a option to disable the device.

That should make sure that the device will no longer be used by Windows

Comment: I'm not sure where exactly you mean but just disabling the device from the sound settings does not work. It uses the right one ONLY if the other one does not exist, no matter if it's selected or disabled.

Answer (score -1):

I partly followed what was suggested in the answer to [this post](https://www.sevenforums.com/hardware-devices/201269-device-manager-disabled-devices-re-enable-restart.html).

I opened regedit and changed

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\HdAudAddService\Start=4`

This made sense, since in the device manager events for the device I could find that HdAudAddService was triggering the installation.